# How to add attachment option in Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I need to make a Google Doc Form, in which the users need to upload a Word file. Is it possible to do so using Google Docs form? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4):

Google Forms does not allow respondents to upload files. There are some ways around this though:

1. Have them upload the file directly to your Drive account. See instructions [here](http://lifehacker.com/allow-others-to-upload-files-to-your-google-drive-with-1567528648).
2. Use [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com/help/192-How-to-Integrate-a-Form-with-Google-Drive), which has integration with Drive.

Answer (score 2):

I also liked James Pearson's tech cogitation blog entry "[Folders as a workaround for Google form attachments](http://techcogitation.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/folders-as-workaround-for-google-form.html)" Using his script once a form is submitted a new folder is created and a link to this folder is sent via email to the person who submitted the form.

Comment: This solution could work but it requires that the form respondent has a Google account and enough free space to be able to upload the files to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

G Suite users could add an upload question type to Google Forms.

From the official help article, [Edit your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en):

> #### Upload files to a form
>
> If you use Google apps through work or school, respondents can upload files as a response to a question.
>   Uploaded files will take up Google Drive storage for the survey owner.
>   Learn how to clear Google Drive space and increase storage.
>
> 1. Open a form in Google Forms.
> 2. Click Add Add.
> 3. Next to the question title, click the Down arrow Down Arrow.
> 4. Click File Upload.
> 5. Click Continue.
>
> After you create your question, you can:
>
> - Adjust the maximum file size.
> - Change the file type.